# Capturing all streams in correct sequence with PowerShell SDK

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-sdk

I'm executing a script with the PowerShell SDK, which makes use of all different streams (information, warning, verbose, ..). I can capture the output from them correctly, but not in the sequence they are generated. As an example, here is a console app (C#, .NET 7, installed the NuGet package *Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK*):

```cs
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;

var runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(InitialSessionState.CreateDefault());
runSpace.Open();

var instance = System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Create(runSpace);

instance.AddScript("""
    $VerbosePreference = 'Continue'

    Write-Verbose "Line 1"
    Write-Output "Line 2"
    Write-Verbose "Line 3"
    Write-Information "Line 4"
    Write-Information "Line 5"
    Write-Verbose "Line 6"
    """
);

var output = instance.Invoke();

foreach (var o in output)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"[N]: {o}");
}

foreach (var v in instance.Streams.Verbose)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"[V]: {v}");
}

foreach (var i in instance.Streams.Information)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"[I]: {i}");
}
```

As you can see I'm returning different results on different streams. When I output them like that of course, they are no longer in the correct order:

```
[N]: Line 2
[V]: Line 1
[V]: Line 3
[V]: Line 6
[I]: Line 4
[I]: Line 5
```

I have been looking at the objects provided by `instance.Streams.Information`, `instance.Streams.Verbose`, etc. - but I could not find a property that would let me sort them. Interestingly `instance.Streams.Information` has a `TimeGenerated`, but it is missing from all the other stream objects!

So I'm stumped how I could accomplish this, would it be possible to get these sorted based on the time they were generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to subscribe to the relevant *event* on each stream collection up front, rather then waiting until execution has finished.

To do so, register handlers for the `DataAdded` event on each relevant `instance.Streams.*` property:

```
var runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(InitialSessionState.CreateDefault());
runSpace.Open();

using (var instance = System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Create(runSpace))
{
    instance.AddScript("""
        $VerbosePreference = 'Continue'

        Write-Verbose "Line 1"
        Write-Output "Line 2"
        Write-Verbose "Line 3"
        Write-Information "Line 4"
        Write-Information "Line 5"
        Write-Verbose "Line 6"
        """
    );

    # register event handler for the DataAdded event on each relevant stream collection
    instance.Streams.Verbose.DataAdded += ConsumeStreamOutput;
    instance.Streams.Information.DataAdded += ConsumeStreamOutput;

    # now create a data collection for standard output
    var outputCollection = new PSDataCollection<PSObject>();
    # ... and register the event handler on that too
    outputCollection.DataAdded += ConsumeStreamOutput;

    # ... and now we're finally ready to invoke the script
    instance.Invoke();
}
```

Now we just need to define and implement the `ConsumeStreamOutput` method that will handle the events. It needs to expect different types of output based on stream it's written to.

```
static void ConsumeStreamOutput(object sender, DataAddedEventArgs evtArgs)
{
    var data = ((System.Collections.IList)sender)[evtArgs.Index];

    switch (data)
    {
        case VerboseRecord vr:
            WriteLine($"Received Verbose stream data     :  '{vr}'");
            break;
        case InformationRecord ir:
            WriteLine($"Received Information stream data :  '{ir}'");
            break;
        default:
            WriteLine($"Received standard output         :  '{data}'");
            break;
    }
}
```

The above should give you an output like:

```
Received Verbose stream data     :  'Line 1'
Received standard output         :  'Line 2'
Received Verbose stream data     :  'Line 3'
Received Information stream data :  'Line 4'
Received Information stream data :  'Line 5'
Received Verbose stream data     :  'Line 6'
```

Of course you can change this method to just collect the data to a single queue or similar if you need to process the data elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you! Funny, I just found another approach just when you posted this. But I'll accept this as the answer as both are great ways of solving this. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

After reading some more about PS hosts, I found the way to do it! Basically it's possible to redirect all other streams to the standard output stream with this line:

```cs
instance.Commands.Commands[0].MergeMyResults(PipelineResultTypes.All,PipelineResultTypes.Output);
```

With that, `instance.Invoke()` returns everything, including verbose, information, etc. streams.

Then by checking what each *PSObject* is, I can do treat the objects differently depending on their type. Full sample:

```cs
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;

var runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(InitialSessionState.CreateDefault());
runSpace.Open();

var instance = PowerShell.Create(runSpace);

instance.AddScript("""
    $VerbosePreference = 'Continue'

    Write-Verbose "Line 1"
    Write-Output "Line 2"
    Write-Error "Line 3"
    Write-Verbose "Line 4"
    Write-Information "Line 5"
    Write-Information "Line 6"
    Write-Verbose "Line 7"
    """
);

instance.Commands.Commands[0].MergeMyResults(PipelineResultTypes.All,PipelineResultTypes.Output);

var output = instance.Invoke();

foreach (var o in output)
{
    switch (o.ImmediateBaseObject)
    {
        case ErrorRecord er:
            Console.WriteLine($"[ERR]: {er}");
            break;
        case WarningRecord wr:
            Console.WriteLine($"[WRN]: {wr}");
            break;
        case VerboseRecord vr:
            Console.WriteLine($"[VER]: {vr}");
            break;
        case InformationRecord ir:
            Console.WriteLine($"[INF]: {ir}");
            break;
        case DebugRecord dr:
            Console.WriteLine($"[DBG]: {dr}");
            break;
        default:
            // I assume everything that ends up here is uncaptured output.
            Console.WriteLine($"[OUT]: {o}");
            break;
    }
}
```

And the output is now in the correct order:

```
[VER]: Line 1
[OUT]: Line 2
[ERR]: Line 3
[VER]: Line 4
[INF]: Line 5
[INF]: Line 6
[VER]: Line 7
```